# vue2 router-link before redirect

Tags: vuejs2, crud

I am using `Vue2`. In Crude List showing all the items and want to redirect to another page in click action `edit button`

I using

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'beneficiary_form'}"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit</router-link>
```

This is an update function I need to pass the id in the link.

Using `vuex` to save the `beneficiary_id`.

```
this.add({
         beneficiary_id        : data.id,                    
});
```

How can I add the `beneficiary_id` before redirect to `beneficiary_form` page?

[image]

I changed the code like

```
<a  href="javascript:void(0)" @click="handleEdit(beneficiary.id)"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit</a>
```

```
 handleEdit(id){
            this.add({
                beneficiary_id        : id,
            });
            console.log(this.$route.name);
            history.pushState(
                    {},
                    null,
                    route('beneficiary_form')
                );
        },
```

this is giving error `route('beneficiary_form')` not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use VueRouter and have configured it correctly, you can use

```js
router.push({ name: 'beneficiary_form' });
```

Then in the form page you can get the `beneficiary_id` from vuex.

See [Vue router Programmatic Navigation DOCS](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html)